# Is known the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\mu(n)}{n^s}$, where $s$ is the complex variable and $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, see its definition for example from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html), and we denote with $s$ the complex variable.

I'm curious to know if some case of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\mu(n)}{n^s}$$
for $\Re s\geq \frac{1}{2}$, were in the literature.

I did simple experiments with Wolfram Alpha and from those my belief is that one can calculate a closed-form for the case $s=2+0\cdot i=2$, and write an identity in terms of the constant $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}$ for the case $s=3$.

> **Question.** Was in the literature the formal series (or complex function defined on a domain of the complex plane) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\mu(n)}{n^s}\,?\tag{1}$$ Then refer the literature and I try to find and read those known facts about the complex function $(1)$. **Many thanks.**

Comment: I doubt it's in the literature, it's simple, but useless.

Comment: Do you know how calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\mu(n)}{n^2}$? Or properties of our function $(1)$ as the convergence abscissa @ProfessorVector ?

Comment: It's trivial to derive from the known result without the $(-1)^n$. Give us a few own thoughts for a change, please!

Comment: Many thanks Professor Vector.

Comment: Is $(-1)^n \mu(n)$ multiplicative ? ...

Comment: Yes, since it is a product of two multiplicative functions. Then you are saying that the same can be deduced using Euler products @reuns

Comment: $(-1)^{n+1}$ is multiplicative not $(-1)^n$. Dirichlet series with multiplicative coefficients $\implies$ Euler product, this is the 1st page of every book on analytic number theory. Can you write this Euler product ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume for a moment that $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$. Then using the fact that $\mu$ is multiplicative, we have

$$ \sum_{n\text{ even}} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(2k)}{(2k)^s}
= - \frac{1}{2^s} \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}. $$

So if we write $D(s) = \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}$, then

$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}
= (1 - 2^{-s})D(s)
$$

and hence

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mu(n)}{n^s}
&= \sum_{n\text{ even}} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} - \sum_{n\text{ odd}} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \\
&= -(1+2^{-s})D(s)
 = - \frac{2^s+1}{2^s-1} \cdot \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Many thanks I would like to study more your answer, but it seems that agree with my examples.

Comment: Looks like we have similarly: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {|\mu(n)|(-1)^n}{n^s}=-\frac{2^{s}-1}{2^{s}+1}\cdot\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)}{\zeta\left(2s\right)}$$